# Can I get the ACTUAL Send Request Body from IE F12 developer?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

Apologies in advance because this isn't a code question, but it's to do with code development -

When monitoring my traffic, specifically POST requests, using Internet Explorer's new version of the F12 developer tool, the request body is broken down in to its key/value pairs and set alphabetically.

For my purposes this is completely rubbish.

It used to just show the ACTUAL request body - is there any way I can revert F12 developer to show this?!

I can't find any documentation on this and searches to do with this yield thousands of results which all seem irrelevant.

Comment: According to your description, I suggest that maybe you could test that if the request body is also broken down when you try to run another url. If it works well when opening another url, maybe it is the url's issue. If not, maybe it is the browser's issue,you may use Fiddler to check the request body.

Comment: I don't think this is a URL issue, it seems to be new behaviour for the F12 developer - it's as if they're trying to help by showing the key/val pairs alphabetically but then the API I'm sending to needs these in the order they're built. I didn't want to have to download Fiddler either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `POST` request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you can only see it as key/value pairs in F12, even if you export it to a HAR file it will be encoded as key value pairs.

In general if you want to see the actual network traffic it's better to use a tool like Fiddler, netmon, or wireshark. The browser tools don't operate at the network layer and might be abstracted away from what actually gets sent. For example the browser tools don't know about the ordering of headers because the stack beneath it (wininet) doesn't keep that information only the parsed key / value pairs.

Comment: I did eventually download Fiddler - It's just one of those annoying things. It used to be completely functional and ideal for me, then they "upgraded" it and now it doesn't work as well as it used to :(